# How to upload multiple files in Oracle Apex 4.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-plugin

How to upload multiple files in Oracle Apex 4.2, currently single file is getting uploaded.
In 4.2 there is no option like we can change the settings for selection of files to be multiple.
Please suggest any quick way to get this done.

Comment: More info needed. Are you asking about loading files in the APEX builder environment (e.g. uploading js and css files), loading files into the APEX data loader, or loading files into your custom application? For the latter, you may want to check out the Dropzone plugin on apex.world. Also, you have tagged this for APEX version 5 and 5.1 but your title says 4.2 - which version are you using?

Comment: asking for multiple files upload in a a page of an application where single file upload functionality is still running.

Comment: In that case, the Dropzone plugin should do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there's no way to do that, unless you - before loading process - merge those files into one. For example, if those are Excel files, copy/paste contents from all files into one of them, and then load that "huge" file in a single loading session.

Comment: http://monkeyonoracle.blogspot.com/2011/10/multiple-file-upload-with-jquery-and.html

Comment: That's more than **wonderful**, @Anshul, thank you for sharing the info. Although, as the author says, it is not Apex itself that does that via its *data loading* capabilities, but jQuery with Apex Listener. I sincerely hope that you'll make it work, but I believe that it still stands: you can't do it via *data load* Apex process. Good luck!